# li nowrap child elements in IE7 not working

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

Using JQuery I add list of elements into a div layer.

My list of elements are constructed as,

```
<li>
    <span>AAA BBB CCCCCCC</span>
    <a href="#">Delete</a>
</li>
```

Please see the image and observe the last element getting braked.
[image]

This is happening in IE6 and IE7 alone.

Tried to couple all the elements with `display:inline` `display:inline-block` `float:left;`

How can I stop wrapping the child elements.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your CSS. Can't do anything without more CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestions helped me to fix it actually. I added `position: absolute` for the anchor tag and `margin-right: 5px` for li and fixed my problem.

Thanks for your suggestions guys.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define `zoom` with `display:inline` for IE7. Write like this:

```
ul{white-space: nowrap;
}

li span, li a{
 display:inline-block;
 *display:inline;/* For IE7*/
 *zoom:1;/* For IE7*/
}
```

Check this it's work in IE7 also http://jsfiddle.net/3jCF9/5/

Remove `float` from your `li` because `white-space:nowrap` is not work on `float` elements.

Answer (score 1):

try `display:block;`
that should do the work. `float:left;` has nothing to do with it !

Comment: Tried. Still not able to fix it.

Comment: then post the rest of your css code to ! but have you added display block on your li items ? Btw why are you having a span and a a tag ? you could add the text of the span to your a or not ?

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work:

```
ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3jCF9/).

Comment: Then make a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can see what you're working with, and see if we can make it work as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the context of that output, but you could try white-space: nowrap; on the parent ul

Comment: added it. Still not able to fix it